# Finding if latitude and longitude in shapefile region

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely

I referenced this [very helpful question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250172/finding-out-if-coordinate-is-within-shapefile-shp-using-pyshp/250195), but still cannot crack the issue.

I downloaded [Zillow's neighborhood shapefile for Connecticut](https://www.zillowstatic.com/static-neighborhood-boundaries/LATEST/static-neighborhood-boundaries/shp/ZillowNeighborhoods-CT.zip) and have a latitude and longitude: `41.344602, -73.071443` which exists in CT, according to Google Maps.

As far as I can see, the shapefile is using the same format, yet when I use the following snippet:

```
import shapefile
import shapely.geometry as geometry
shapefile_location = 'C:/Downloads/zillow_ct_neighborhood_boundaries/ZillowNeighborhoods-CT.shp'
shp = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_location)
pt = 41.344602, -73.071443
all_shapes = shp.shapes() # get all the polygons
all_records = shp.records()
for i in range(0,len(all_shapes)):

    boundary = all_shapes[i] # get a boundary polygon
    print( all_records[i][2],boundary.points)
    name_ =  all_records[i][2]
    if 'New Haven' in name_:
        ok_regions.append(boundary)
    #     print(name_,geometry.Point(pt).within(geometry.shape(boundary)))
        if geometry.Point(pt).within(geometry.shape(boundary)): # make a point and see if it's in the polygon
            name_ = all_records[i][2] # get the second field of the corresponding record
            print("The point is in", name  )
```

I also tried to reverse the `latitude, longitude` combo, but no luck. My code does not find my latitude, longitude combo in any of the neighborhoods.

Does anyone have some guidance on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: You need to verify that all_shapes has the same CRS (e.g. epsg:4326) as shp. Also, you might want to look into geopandas which will let you do this without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your point does not fall within any of the polygons of your shapefile. It falls somewhere in Ansonia. Your code will never find a matching polygon for that coordinate:

[image]

Comment: What did you use for this plot?

Comment: I simply displayed the shapefile in Google Earth Pro